# Wordpress / Fluent Form / ACF : One Post by user edit & update

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I created an ACF post type named "Profile"

I want logged in users to be able to fill out their own profile and edit it via Fluent Form.
A user only has one "Profile" post content, so when he goes to the Fluent Form linked to the ACF "Profile" content, he either creates a new post if he does not have one , or it updates its existing information.

So I use "Post/CPT Creation" with a Post Feed.

If I use Submission Type "New Post", one user can create multiple profile (it's not what I want)

If I use Submission Type "Update Post" the content is not created. Maybe I need to create 2 Post Feed on "New Post" and another "Update Post". I don't understand well...

I've also tried the "Post Update" field but as each user only has one post, I find that it makes no sense to ask them to select their profile in this select. (even if I limit the field with its userid)

Is there a way to have a form that if a user don't have any Profile he can create it. And if he already have a profile the form will load its information to allow hime to update it.

I have de PHP / Javscript Dev so I can use snippets (function.php) if this is a solution.

Thanks

Samuel

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Ibrahim Mustafa !

Your solution was good but the fluentfilter have changed

Here is my solution :

```
// return the ACF Post Id of current user
function user_has_family_post() {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'family', // Adjust post type as needed
        'author'    => $user_id,
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
    );    
    $query = new WP_Query($args);    
    $query->have_posts();
    $query->the_post();
    return get_the_ID();
}
// modify FluentForm to set :
// - user_has_family_post to true or false (use on conditionnal in fluentform submition type "create" or "update")
// - fluentform "post_update" field to ACF Post Id of user content
function set_user_has_family_field_value($form) {
    $profile_id = user_has_family_post();
    
    foreach($form->fields["fields"] as $key => $field):       
        if($field["attributes"]["name"] == 'user_has_family_post') {
            $form->fields["fields"][$key]["attributes"]["value"] = $profile_id ? 'true' : 'false';
        }
        if($field["attributes"]["name"] == 'post_update') {
            $form->fields["fields"][$key]["attributes"]["value"] = $profile_id;
        }        
    endforeach;
    return $form;
} 
add_filter('fluentform/rendering_form', 'set_user_has_family_field_value', 10, 2);
```